# ASP.NET MVC - C# - Define Key Value Pair for use in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app needs to display breadcrumbs representing the user's location in the app. In an effort to do this, I wanted to have something like the following in a master layout page:

```
@foreach(var link in ViewBag["Links"])
{
  <div>|</div>
  <a href="@link.url">@link.text</a>
}
```

Then, in each view, I'd have something like the following at the top:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Layouts/_Breadcrumbed.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Links = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Home", "/home" },
        { "Parent", "/parent" }
    };
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following error:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'
```

I do not understand why I'm getting that. Am I doing down the correct path for creating a breadcrumb? If not, what approach is better?

Comment: What happens if you replace `ViewBag["Links"]` with `ViewBag.Links`?

Comment: @David there's no diference, the issue is related to ViewBag using dynamic, not strongly typed. He must cast the Links variable to Dictionary

Comment: Although it is confusing to use ["Links"] in one place and .Links in another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast ViewBag["Links"] to your dictionary so foreach knows what to iterate on.

```
@foreach(var link in (IDictionary<string, string>)ViewBag["Links"])
```